# What is the Substitute of ServletContextListner of java in Asp.net

Tags: c#, java, asp.net

I have Used ServletContextListner in java web application for invoking a method before the start of the web application and deployed the web appliction in apache tomcat ..Now i have got similar requirement in Asp.net but i dont know what is the substitute of ServletContextListner    of this in asp.net..

Basically i have a function in my application which takes hours to complete and needs to start at the boot time of the system as soon as the server iis starts.

In java web application i have put this method in a thread of ServletContextListner so that i should not affect the accessing of web pages and execute the method in background...

Please guys help me..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: I don't believe that such a long-lived operation belongs in a webserver (which can recycle at any point). I'd consider spinning this out to a windows service with which your app communicates, perhaps via WCF

Comment: @spender i have my existing app working as windows service only but due to performance issue and as i have got solution in java so wanted to change

Comment: @spender Does AppInitialize() will do the needfull and can it be used in Classic asp.net